# Informix + SQLAlchemy looking for table that doesn't exist

Tags: sqlalchemy, db2, informix

I'm trying to connect to an Informix database with SQLAlchemy.  All my tests seem to show the connection is working; however, whenever I try and perform a read of the database I get the error:

```
DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) SQLCODE -217 in PREPARE: 
IX000: Column (current_role) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
 'select CURRENT_ROLE from systables' ()
```

Now the database that I am connecting to doesn't have CURRENT_ROLE, so how can I get round this?

My interactive traceback of the error is shown below in a gist:

https://gist.github.com/2157378

The offending line is:

```
 File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/sqlalchemy/dialects/informix/base.py", line 593, in _get_default_schema_name
    return connection.execute('select CURRENT_ROLE from systables').scalar()
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

I am now led to believe this is a bug in SQLAlchemy (after talking to users in #sqlalchemy) and I have filed a bug report:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/ticket/2448

Answer (score 0):

You've not identified which version of IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) you are using or which platform you are using it on, so it is hard to help you.

It appears that SQLAlchemy expects a more recent version of Informix than you are using.  Somewhat to my surprise, the niladic function CURRENT_ROLE appears to be available in IDS 11.70 (tested on 11.70.FC4 on RHEL 5 for x86/64).  It was not recently added, so it will be in any 11.70 version, and possibly in some earlier versions (but not as early as the version you are using).

I'm not sure how much of a bug it is in SQLAlchemy.  If the version of Informix that you're using is really old, there is limited virtue in them adding support for it.  You can find out which version you're using by running:

```
SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full')
  FROM 'informix'.systables
 WHERE tabid = 1;
```

If that doesn't work, you are many years out of date with your server.

---

#### Addendum

Thinking about it a bit more...I wonder what SQLAlchemy is going to do with the role.  It probably shouldn't be trying to analyze whether you have permission; it should try an operation and deal with failures.  That will be quicker, especially in the common case where you actually do have permission.

There could be two issues:

1. SQLAlchemy should be aware that some (as yet indeterminate) list of old versions of IDS do not support CURRENT_ROLE.
2. SQLAlchemy should review why it needs to be aware of the current role.